# QT QML signal does not get to a Canvas when defined in style: ButtonStyle

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am quite new to QML and I am trying to make a QML `Button` change it's background when an event happens. The `Button` uses `style: ButtonStyle` and a `Canvas` to generate some graphics (via JavaScript). I am using QML `State`s to control the `Button` state.

I figured out that the `Canvas` does not refresh automatically so I tried to call `requestPaint()` inside the `onStateChanged` handler, but this signal somehow does not get to the canvas when it is defined in the `style` property.

Here is my code:

```
Button {
    id: small_rounded_button
    state: "OFF"
    states: [
        State {
            name: "ON"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: small_rounded_button
                backgroundColor: "#18243C"
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "OFF"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: small_rounded_button
                backgroundColor: "#aaa"
            }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (small_rounded_button.enabled == true)
            {
                if (small_rounded_button.state == "ON")
                {
                    small_rounded_button.state = "OFF"
                }
                else
                {
                    small_rounded_button.state = "ON"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Item {
            Canvas {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPaint: {
                    var ctx = getContext("2d");
                    ctx.reset();

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineWidth = height * 0.1;
                    ctx.roundedRect(ctx.lineWidth / 2, ctx.lineWidth / 2,
                                    width - ctx.lineWidth, height - ctx.lineWidth, small_rounded_button.radius, small_rounded_button.radius);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
                    ctx.stroke();

                    /* this definitely sets the colour when app starts */
                    ctx.fillStyle = small_rounded_button.backgroundColor;

                    ctx.fill();
                }

                /* This never happens */
                onStateChanged: {
                    requestPaint()
                }
            }

            Label {
                text: small_rounded_button.text
                color: "#000"
                font.pixelSize: small_rounded_button.height * 0.5
                //anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
            label: null
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implemented `onStateChanged` handler inside your `Canvas`, which doesn't change the state, but your `Button` does.

You can use signals and slots to archive what you want:

```
Canvas {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        small_rounded_button.stateChanged.connect(requestPaint);
    }
}
```

Anyhow, there were more problems in your code, here's a correctly working version:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls  1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Button {
    id: small_rounded_button
    property string backgroundColor : "#f0f"
    state: "OFF"
    states: [
        State {
            name: "ON"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: small_rounded_button
                backgroundColor: "#18243C"
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "OFF"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: small_rounded_button
                backgroundColor: "#aaa"
            }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (small_rounded_button.enabled == true)
            {
                if (small_rounded_button.state == "ON")
                {
                    small_rounded_button.state = "OFF"
                }
                else
                {
                    small_rounded_button.state = "ON"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Item {
            Canvas {
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    requestPaint();
                    small_rounded_button.stateChanged.connect(requestPaint);
                }
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPaint: {
                    var ctx = getContext("2d");
                    ctx.reset();

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineWidth = height * 0.1;
                    ctx.roundedRect(ctx.lineWidth / 2, ctx.lineWidth / 2,
                    width - ctx.lineWidth, height - ctx.lineWidth, small_rounded_button.radius, small_rounded_button.radius);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
                    ctx.stroke();

                    /* this definitely sets the colour when app starts */
                    ctx.fillStyle = small_rounded_button.backgroundColor;

                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                }

            }

            Label {
                text: small_rounded_button.text
                color: "#000"
                font.pixelSize: small_rounded_button.height * 0.5
                //anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have a follow up question; I'm trying to do something similar with a slider.  When the slider value changes, I want the canvas to redraw.  I've tried giving the canvas an id and calling redraw events from the sliders onValueChanged method, but like BaCaRoZzo, I wasn't able to get that to work.  So I tried finding how to connect the canvas to the slider, similarly to what you have as a solution, aep, but I can't find the method for slider to attach to.  Do you have any ideas?